# Push local master commits to remote branch

Tags: git

I've been working on a local clone of a remote git repository, committing my changes to my local master branch. Now, I want to push my commits to the remote repository. However, I want to keep my local commits separate from the remote master branch, so that I don't break anything. How can I push my local commits to a new remote branch?

Comment: Why not merge to a local tracking branch and then push the local branch to the remote branch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I push a local Git branch to master branch in the remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423517/how-do-i-push-a-local-git-branch-to-master-branch-in-the-remote)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should run `git help push`, which will tell you about the syntax for the refspec that you push to. In short, `git push <remotename> <local_branch_name>:<remote_branch_name>`

Comment: For me I had to do
     `git remote` (get the remote name, mine was origin)
     `git push -f origin UI-Addition:UI-Addition`
W/o the `-f` option it would not allow the operation.

Comment: This fails for me.  It says `error: unable to push to unqualified destination: temp2
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.`

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to do this with a single command.  First I commit all my changes to my local master.  Then I create a new local branch called "mybranch" using

```
git checkout -b mybranch
```

and then I pushed that using

```
git push -u origin mybranch
```

in my case `origin` is the remote name.  Your remote name might be different.  You can use `git remote -v` to see what your remote name should be.

After the push, if you want, you can get rid of your local branch using these two commands

```
git checkout master
git branch -d mybranch
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was creatE a new local branch for example name it `test1`

`> git checkout -b test1`

This command will create a branch and switch to it directly, and then push your new local branch to your remote repository either GitHub or GitLab by typing

`> git push origin test1`

don't forget to check the correct link by typing.

`> git remote --v`