# How to fast forward a remote branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have a local `master branch` and remote `master` and `production` branches

My `master` is corresponding to the remote `master` (act like the trunk, but no fully tested for deployment, so I have create a branch called `production` which is always behind the `master`)

e.g. `git branch -a`

```
* master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/production
```

When I push, i will always push to the `master`, but at sometimes, I feel the quality is good enough and I want the `production` branch to catch up the changes in `master`, what command I should use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I push a local Git branch to master branch in the remote?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423517/how-do-i-push-a-local-git-branch-to-master-branch-in-the-remote)

Comment: I recommend to have a look at the git documentation (http://git-scm.com/documentation) to make yourself familiar with the basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others [have stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605895/how-to-fast-forward-a-remote-branch#comment13740411_10605895):

```
git push origin master:production
```