# git push to branch by other name

Tags: git, push, git-remote

I base git remote myproject on remote upstream from github. Now I have branch master tracking myproject/master but want to have another branch tracking upstream/master, so I create branch upstream-master.

- Getting changes from upstream/master is easy, just do *git pull upstream* when on local/master
- It is good to have a local branch upstream-master to prepare commits to upstream/master

  - To copy commits from master to upstream-master: *git merge master*
  - To see pending commits on upstream-master: *git log @{upstream}..*
  - To automatically squash merge commits and such: *git rebase -i @{upstream}*

For some reason one cannot automatically push from local/upstream-master to upstream/master. This works:

```
git co upstream-master
git push upstream HEAD:master
```

This is ineffective, upstream is not changed

```
git co upstream-master
git push --set-upstream upstream HEAD:master
```

This affects local/master

```
git co upstream-master
git push --set-upstream upstream master
```

Why is it not possible to configure so that *git push* wih no arguments pushes from local/upstream-master to upstream/master?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified) what you are looking for?

Comment: What is wrong with doing `git push origin local_master : upstream_master`, or am I missing the point?  Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I push a local Git branch to master branch in the remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423517/how-do-i-push-a-local-git-branch-to-master-branch-in-the-remote)